# Client ID not showing

Tags: flutter, webrtc, nestjs

I need to make a video calling mobile application using Webrtc on flutter. I found an Github project with all the similar functionalities so I tried to run it on my machine using the read me file. now the application is running but the client id is not generated to make the call so please somebody help me by providing a detailed procedure to run it.
link: https://github.com/nhancv/nc-flutter-webrtc-ex

Comment: Please post your code that you used here. We cannot help you when you don't describe your problem in your code.

Comment: i just tried to the run the github project but i couldnt

Comment: Please post error logs and run flutter pub get in your terminal. We can't help you without any details.